# Как мне получить доступ к локальному виртуальному серверу на телефоне?

Tags: администрирование, виртуальная-машина

**Имеется**: компьютер с виртуальной машиной (**ip** 192.168.0.14), роутер DIR-615, сайт в виртуальной машине (**ip-host** 192.168.174.1 **ip-guest** 192.168.174.133)

**Реализовано**: доступ к сайту с компьютера по DNS имени default.dev. Т.е. с компа я ввожу DNS default.dev и у меня в браузере отображается сайт, находящийся в виртуалке.

**Соображения**: Я так понимаю, что в моем роутере надо произвести настройку а-ля виртуальный сервер, для перенаправления запроса на комп, но в интернете данной информации никак найти не могу (или, как вариант, это я слишком тупой, ятобы понять что, где, куда и зачем)

**Требуется**: "расшарить" сайт из виртуалки на всю локальную сеть. Т.е., например, я ввожу название локального сайта на телефоне *"default.dev"*, запрос идет через роутер к компу, который перенаправляет запрос на виртуалку.

Comment: У вас получается зайти через телефон на 192.168.174.133?

Comment: @Daniil вот именно, что нет. Получается выйти только на ip компьютера (192.168.0.14). Мне надо выйти на ip виртуальной машины (192.168.174.133), причем желательно по DNS имени. (хочу написать сайт, чтобы все домашние смотрели фильмы с моего сервака)

Comment: А виртуальную машину видно в интерфейсе роутера (имеется ввиду 192.168.174.133)?

Comment: 1. нет, не видно. 

2. Тут надо сделать проброс на компьютер, потом отдельно сделать проброс на виртуальку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind на виртуалку поставить и настроить, и заставить роутер его указывать в качестве DNS для всех устройств в сети?

Про то как виртуалку выставить в сеть бриджом - уже выше написали.

Comment: Вот это самый верный вариант

Comment: **заставить роутер его указывать в качестве DNS** не понял. Как это реализовать? Нигде не видел в настройках роутера, что можно подменить DNS

Answer (score 2):

Телефон ничего не "знает" о домене default.dev.
Насколько я понял из описания, default.dev - это доменное имя виртуального компьютера с ip 192.168.174.133.
Если вы настроите подключение виртуалки в сеть методом моста (Bridge в настройках сетевого подключения виртуальной машины) и автоматическое получение IP-адреса, то гостевая операционка сможет получить ip-адрес от роутера.
Тогда ваш телефон, роутер, реальный компьютер и виртуальная машина будут все в одной сети и телефон сможет разрешить имя default.dev в ip-адрес с помощью роутера.
Готов помочь, задавайте вопросы.
В свою очередь мои вопросы:

1. Какие ОС установлены на реальном компьютере и гостевой машинке?
2. Какая прошивка на DIR-615? Родная или кастомная? Какая версия прошивки? Если кастомная, то какая?

Comment: Для комментария нужно 50 репутации...
А я могу помочь в данном вопросе. Не смог промолчать.

Comment: 1. На реальном компе установлена Windows XP (по барабану, что ее не поддерживает microsoft :) ), на гостевой - Debian 7

2. Прошивка, как я понимаю кастомная (т.е. данный аппарат покупался отдельно в магазине и к оператору/провайдеру не имеет никакого отношения). Версия прошивки 2.5.14. Если надо, могу скинуть вам скриншот

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. 1. В настройках виртуальной машины поставьте подключение типа Мост (Bridge). 2. В настройках Debian сделайте автоматическое получение айпи-адреса по DHCP. 3. После получения виртуальной машиной ip-адреса, с реального компьютера попробуйте зайти на виртуальную машину по доменному имени. 4. Убедитесь, что виртуальная машина и телефон находятся в одной подсети (по ip-адресам и маске подсети). 5. Попробуйте зайти с браузера телефона на виртуальную машину по ip-адресу. 6. Попробуйте зайти с браузера телефона на виртуальную машину по доменному имени.

Comment: Допустим, что по Ip-адресу запрос идет (просто сам компьютер на данный момент занят). Как обмануть DNS? если работать с ОС - там всегда есть файл hosts, на крайний случай. Меня главное волнует вопрос, сумеет ли роутер переправить определенное имя ( default.dev для примера ) на определенный Ip

Comment: Необходимо выполнять то, что я написал, по пунктам.
Нужно, чтобы виртуальная машина, роутер и телефон были в одной подсети и при этому у виртуальной машины и у телефона в качестве DNS-сервера был прописан роутер. Тогда роутер сможет для телефона разрешить доменное имя в ip-адрес виртуальной машины.

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть только один внешний IP на всю домашнюю сеть — тот, что выдал провайдер проводного интернета вашему роутеру. И даже этот адрес может меняться время от времени. Поэтому надо решить несколько подзадач:

1. чтобы виртуалка имела свой адрес во внутренней сети.
2. динамический маппинг домена во внешнем мире на адрес вашего роутера
3. проброс порта в роутере на виртуалку

Первое делается через bridged network в настройках виртуалки.

Второе можно сделать через публичные сервисы DNS. Например freedns.afraid.org см. Dynamic DNS: у вас будет "секретная ссылка", которую вы можете по крону "пинговать" чтобы домен всегда смотрел на актуальный адрес.

Третье есть в настройках роутера.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно белый айпи, так же поставить сайт на данный айпи, потом в днс у провайдера если не ошибаюсь прописывать данные, чтобы домен привязался к данному айпи.
Если же у вас денвер или тому подобное, тогда сайт у вас прописан в настройках ос.
В данном файле прописывается.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts

Comment: если я правильно вас понял, то таким образом я выложу свой сайт в интернет. Мне же надо сделать его доступным только для **локальной сети** т.е. для тех, кто сидит за моим роутером DIR 615.   Насколько я понимаю должны быть настроки, чтобы перебрасывать запрос на определенный ip **внутри сети**, в данном случае на 192.168.0.14. Далее мой комп, у которого прописано в файле hosts **192.168.174.133 default.dev** перебросит запрос на виртуалку

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, нельзя подставить телефону DNS-сервера и уж точно файл hosts из роутера.

В таком случае существует несколько решений:

1. Прорутить телефон и отредактировать /etc/hosts
2. *(сложнее)* Поднять локальные DNS и прописать их в настройках телефона
3. Поднимать каждый отдельный виртуальный хост или приложение на своем порту (это нормальная практика для отладки, выглядит лучше, чем модифицирование хостов или поднятие локального DNS-сервера) и просто обращаться по локальному айпишнишку.

Comment: Для чего я и указал модель своего роутера. В менюшке у него есть такой раздел "Виртуальный сервер", если я правильно понял, то он должен перекидывать запросы исходящие из локалки на определенный ip-адрес. Вопрос только в его настройке. и дальнейшей проброске на виртуалку

Comment: @garmayev Виртуальные сервера в настройках роутера нужны для того, чтобы пробрасывать порты по протоколам. Иначе говоря, при обращении из внешнего интернета на ваш айпишник роутер решает, на какой локальный компьютер передать запрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал. Тогда как обмануть телефон? Чтобы тел обращался по DNS имени, но пересылался на мой ip-адрес, не на интернетовский?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поместить на айпишник вашего компьютера внутри роутера, сайт, в денвере будет вида, home\192.168.0.41\www\  тогда все кто пользуется роутером, будут его видеть по адресу 192.168.0.41.

Comment: 1. денвер как локальный сервер - отпадает

Comment: 2. Сам сервер будет находится на виртуальной машине под управление Debian.